# Pre HoW vanguard weapon aquisition

Tags: destiny

I would like to know if it is at all possible to acquire weapons that the **Vanguard Quartermaster** sold previous to the House of Wolves expansion being released.

This includes

- Weapons from the vanilla game, pre The Dark Below, e.g., Doctor Nope, The Comedian.
- Weapons from the Dark Below expansion, e.g., Badger CCL, LDR 5001

If so, how would one go about acquiring them? Such as Pre HoW strike playlists or rare drops in the crucible?

**Note** I am not asking if you can acquire Pre HoW armour.

Comment: I do not believe that is possible to go back to. The only possible way, and it may not even work, would be to uninstall the game and start over from the original version.

Comment: @TravisJ, as the game requires internet connection, it will not allow you to play without updating first.

Comment: It may be possible with Roc / Tiger strikes, but it'll be *very* slow and very RNG, because the only relevant chance is end of mission rewards, as the engrams that drop in those strikes are HoW level engrams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to get those old weapons. It's really hard and it's a long shot - but here's how you'd do it:

Run the pre-expansion strike playlists, preferably the level 24 one (Tiger). Any rewards you get at the **end mission screen** will be locked in at vanilla level loot. NOTE: If you get an engram *during* the Strike, it'll be HoW level.

Comment: You'll need to run the level 26 strike playlist (ROC) in order for a chance at TDB engrams.

Comment: I gathered as much but wasn't quite sure. Let the tiger strikes begin!

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get vanilla gear at all, is by attempting the Vanguard Viper, Eagle, Wolf and Tiger.